# Merging two groups

Tags: algorithm, c++11, data-structures

I have lots of groups, each group has min range and max range they can fit into. these ranges are overlapping between different group

For eg

```
    Group1  Min Range 3.125 , Max Range 3.5
    Group2  Min Range 3.25 , max Range 3.75
    Group 3 Min Range 3.5, max range 4.0
```

I need to merge these groups to form minimum number groups.

Like

```
Group1  Min Range 3.125 , Max Range 3.5
              Item 1 value 3.125
              Item 2 value 3.3
              Item 3 value 3.5

Group2  Min Range 3.25 , max Range 3.75
              Item 1 value 3.25
              Item 2 value 3.3
```

I can merge these two group in Group1.

This is what I am doing

```
for( size_t TopIndex = 0; TopIndex < GroupVector.Size(); TopIndex++)
{
    Group& CurrentGroup = GroupVector[TopIndex];
    for( size_t InnerIndex = TopIndex +1; InnerIndex < GroupVector.Size(); InnerIndex++)
    {
        Group& InnerGroup  = GroupVector[InnerIndex];
        MergeGroup(CurrentGroup,InnerGroup);
    }
}
```

In MergeGroup,

```
1.  Move items from Group 1 to Group 2 , Save total number of group after merge (I will stop if number of group is 1)
2.  Move items from Group 2 to Group 1 , Save total number of group after merge
3.  Compare number of group form step 1 &2  and accept an option which results in less number of groups.
```

My number of groups to merge is large and I am trying to find if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: In your example with item, what if group2 have an item3 value 3.6? Would you move the 2 first item to group one or none of them?

Comment: Ideally, my aim is to have a minimum number of the groups, for your eg I will move items assuming, maybe 3.6 could be moved to another group in next iterations.

Comment: Check out [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). This seems to be exactly the problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple algorithme to perform what you want.
Personnaly, i would first check if a group can be "absorbed" by the others by checking min and max range.

Exemple:

```
group1 min 1.00, max 2.00
group2 min 1.50, max 2.50
group3 min 1.25, max 2.25
```

all items of group3 can be merge in group 2 and 3.

This will be the first minimal reduction. Then i would check item on the others groups

```
Group1  Min Range 3.10 , Max Range 3.50
              Item 1 value 3.12
              Item 2 value 3.30
              Item 3 value 3.50

Group2  Min Range 3.25 , max Range 3.75
              Item 1 value 3.25
              Item 2 value 3.30

Group3  Min Range 3.30 , max Range 3.90
              Item 1 value 3.40
              Item 2 value 3.50
```

with an algorithm to check if items can be merge in next groups
something like:

```
foreach (groups as group){
    foreach(group.items as item){
        tryToInsertItemIntoOtherGroups(item);
        if(group is empty){
            delete groupe;
        }
    }
}
```

first loop (for first group) would change like this:

```
Group1  Min Range 3.10 , Max Range 3.50
              Item 1 value 3.12

Group2  Min Range 3.25 , max Range 3.75
              Item 1 value 3.25
              Item 2 value 3.30
              Item 3 value 3.30
              Item 4 value 3.50

Group3  Min Range 3.30 , max Range 3.90
              Item 1 value 3.40
              Item 2 value 3.50
```

second loop (for second group) would result of deleting group 2:

```
Group1  Min Range 3.10 , Max Range 3.50
              Item 1 value 3.12
              Item 2 value 3.25
              Item 3 value 3.30
              Item 4 value 3.30
              Item 5 value 3.50

Group3  Min Range 3.30 , max Range 3.90
              Item 1 value 3.40
              Item 2 value 3.50
```

third loop (for third group) would result of deleting group 3:

```
Group1  Min Range 3.10 , Max Range 3.50
              Item 1 value 3.12
              Item 2 value 3.25
              Item 3 value 3.30
              Item 4 value 3.30
              Item 5 value 3.50
              Item 6 value 3.40
              Item 7 value 3.50
```